# Variable checking in Python

Tags: python, variables, integer

I have been trying to find out ways to check about variable types or while do statements but I got confused and didn't know what's going on, on my code.
I want to check if end is an integer so I made up my mind with this.
Thanks a lot!!

```
checked=0
while (checked==0):
    end=input('Give me an integer number!')
    if  isinstance(end,(int)):
        checked=1
    else:
        checked=0
        print('This is not an integer!')
```

Comment: The output of `input` will always be a string, no matter what you enter there. You could do `if str(int(end)) == end:`

Comment: If you're using Python 3, `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: `end`  will always be a string because that is what input returns.

Comment: Considering that I use python 2.7.6 do I have to change anything on what you said? @L3viathan

Comment: Looks like you're probably after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: @ThanosA: Why don't you try it? (I wouldn't think so)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Python motto ["Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) , you could do the following:

```
while True:
  try:
    end = int(input("Enter an integer"))
    break
  except ValueError:
    print("that's no integer")
```

If the conversion to `int` fails, the `break` is skipped and execution continues in the `except ValueError` handler. If the conversion is successful, the `break` exits the loop and you can be sure that `end` is an integer.

Comment: What I can't understand, though I found many topics with while True, is the way this loop continues. It continues each time end is not an integer?

Comment: It continues forever, *unless* it succeeds (because it then `break`s out of the loop).

Comment: the `break` terminates it after a successful converstion of the input to `int`. If the conversion fails, the `break` is skipped.

Comment: I get the following error now after having copied the above code: ...except value error:
SyntaxError :Invalid Syntax

Comment: There must have been edited to ValueError from Value Error

Comment: Yes but what happens if end is not integer for example wouldn't it hit an error message because of end=int(...)?

Comment: No, that's excatly what exceptions are made for. You `try` something that can go wrong. This code is executed `except` some error occurs. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

User input will always be a string unless casted. Use a `try/except` block.

```
try:
    entry = int(input('Enter a integer: '))

except:
    print('That's not an integer.')
```

Comment: Don't use eval for a simple converting. Eval is dangeroooous

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I removed it.

Comment: A bare `except` is also bad. Why reproduce my answer?

Comment: I actually didn't intend to copy your answer.